# Disabling FieldCalcBar in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

Is there a way to disable the FieldCalcBar thingy, which appears in attribute table when the layer is in editing mode? I suppose there should be a checkbox in Settings -> Customization... dialog window, but so far haven't found the right one.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to disable this. Might be worth a feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the FieldCalcBar by using a little bit of Python. The following code defines a function which hides the FieldCalcBar  and connects the `Open Attribute Table` and the `Toggle Editing` buttons to the function so that whenever either is clicked, the FieldCalcBar is hidden. Type the following into the **Python Console:**

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

# Define function to close expression box
def close_expressionBox():
    for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() 
        if d.objectName() == u'QgsAttributeTableDialog' or d.objectName() == u'AttributeTable' ]
        for tables in attrTables:
            for x in tables.children():
                if x.objectName() == 'mActionToggleEditing':
                    try:
                        x.triggered.disconnect(close_expressionBox)
                    except TypeError:
                        pass
                    x.triggered.connect(close_expressionBox)
                if x.objectName() == 'mUpdateExpressionBox':
                    x.hide()

# Connect function to "Open Attribute Table" button
for x in iface.attributesToolBar().actions(): 
    if x.objectName() == 'mActionOpenTable':
        x.triggered.connect(close_expressionBox)

# Connect function to "Toggle Editing" button
for x in iface.digitizeToolBar().actions(): 
    if x.objectName() == 'mActionToggleEditing':
        x.triggered.connect(close_expressionBox)
```

---

Example:

- **Before:**

  [image: Before]

---

- **After:**

  [image: After]

---

*Note: This does not work if accessing the attribute table via right-clicking the layer, as the option is not connected to the function (whereas the option from the `Edit` menubar is...).*

Comment: Its almost a good answer, but, as you pointed out, it doesn't work if the attribute table is opened via right-click on the layer. And it doesn't work at all with QGIS v2.14 or older (tested on v2.6.1, v2.14.2, v2.16.1 and v2.18.11). Is there any other ways?

Comment: @Marty - I'm not sure if there is another way. I tested this on QGIS 2.18.2 so I'm surprised that it doesn't work in atleast 2.18.11. You could always try and submit a [feature request](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis) :)

Comment: it does work on QGIS versions 2.16.1 and 2.18.11 (doesn't work at all with 2.14 or older), so i guess it's the best we can hope at the moment. Thanks for your effort.