# Hide the "Quick Field Calculation Bar" in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table

I want to hide the Quick Field Calculation Bar (see image). I found this old thread:
[Disabling FieldCalcBar in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251268/disabling-fieldcalcbar-in-qgis)

but sadly it does'nt work in QGIS 3.28.

Does anyone know what the quick field calculation bar is called in the Python-API?

I found this in the source code of qgis:

mUpdateExpressionBox->setVisible( mLayer->isEditable() );
if ( mLayer->isEditable() && mFieldCombo->currentIndex() == -1 )

Is it possible to just make the setVisible to false?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Import necessary modules
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication

# Get a reference to the main application
app = QApplication.instance()

# Iterate through all open windows and hide the "Quick Field Calculation" box
for widget in app.allWidgets():
    if widget.objectName() == 'mUpdateExpressionBox':
        widget.setVisible(False)
```

found it out myself!